# N conditions in dynamically 'when' clause

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, when
from functools import reduce
df = spark.createDataFrame([ (1,""), (2,None),(3,"c"),(4,"d") ], ['id','name'])

filter1 = col("name").isNull()
filter2 = col("name") == ""

dfresult = df.filter(filter1 | filter2).select(col("id"), when(filter1, "name is null").when(filter2, "name is empty").alias("new_col"))
dfresult.show()
```

```text
+---+-------------+
| id|      new_col|
+---+-------------+
|  1|name is empty|
|  2| name is null|
+---+-------------+
```

In the scenario with N filters. I think about

```
filters = []
filters.append({ "item": filter1, "msg":"name is null"})
filters.append({ "item": filter2, "msg":"name is empty"})

dynamic_filter = reduce(
    lambda x,y: x | y,
    [s['item'] for s in filters]
)

df2 = df.filter(dynamic_filter).select(col("id"), when(filter1, "name is null").when(filter2, "name is empty").alias("new_col"))
df2.show()
```

How can I make something better for `new_col` column with dynamic `when`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `functools.reduce` as your already did for the filter expression:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

new_col = reduce(
    lambda acc, x: acc.when(x["item"], F.lit(x["msg"])),
    filters,
    F
)

df2 = df.filter(dynamic_filter).select(col("id"), new_col.alias("new_col"))

df2.show()
#+---+-------------+
#| id|      new_col|
#+---+-------------+
#|  1|name is empty|
#|  2| name is null|
#+---+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was blind